# how to compile code using external dll library

Tags: c++

I want to compile program with one file test.cpp, which use external library (i have dll and lib). How to do that?

My test.cpp

```
#include <ExternalLib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#define USE_USB_AUTO_CONNECT 1

int main()
{
   printf ("Characters: %c %c \n", 'a', 65);
   return 0;
}
```

ExternalLib is provided by third part company with files: ExternalLib.lib and ExternalLib.dll. There are also files with extension so and a.

When I compile with command:

```
 g++ test.cpp
```

I get error:

```
test.cpp:1:20: fatal error: ExternalLib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ExternalLib.h>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: First locate ExternalLib.h on PC

Comment: I have also ExternalLib.h

Comment: What do you use windows or Linux

Comment: I use windows but after I will do it in linux

Comment: g++ can't find the _ExternalLib.h_ file, add `-I<path/to/external/lib/header>` to the command. Take a look [here](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse326/02wi/unix/g++.html) to get an idea on how to use g++

Comment: Provide ExternalLib.h and ExternalLib so file name and path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to use dll files (compiled in Windows) under Linux, that will not work.

Anyway your error is that the compiler isn't able to locate your header file, to solve this you have several options:

1) Provide the include path when compiling using `-I` switch
i.e.: `g++ test.cpp -I<path to your include directory>`

2) Copy the *ExternalLib.h* to the same directory in which *test.cpp* lies and use `#include "ExternalLib.h"` instead of `#include <ExternalLib.h>`

3) Provide relative path to *ExternalLib.h* starting from the directory in which *test.cpp* lies. That is, replace `#include <ExternalLib.h>` for `#include "../../external/ExternalLib.h"`

This will solve the **No such file or directory** problem. Then you will also have to provide the binary/library files using `-L` (for library path) and `-l` (for library file) switches.

Comment: so my lib is int directory /lib and dll file is in /lib/dynamic. Could you write how to include it? I try >g++ -o test -L./lib -lExternalLib test.cpp